# Nuxt Proxy Config: How do I create use Array mode?

Tags: javascript, proxy, nuxt.js

In `nuxt-config.js` why does proxying work in object mode but not in array mode?

**Works:** proxying /api/v2/inventory/3906 to nitro.noxgroup.co.za/v2/inventory/3906

```
proxy: {
    '/api': {
        target: 'https://nitro.noxgroup.co.za',
        pathRewrite: {
            '^/api': '/'
        }
    }
},
```

**"Array Mode" Doesn't Work:** In addition, trying to proxy a currency exchange service

```
proxy: [
    {'/api': {
        target: 'https://nitro.noxgroup.co.za',
        pathRewrite: {
            '^/api': '/'
        }
    }},
    {'/api-currency': {
        target: 'https://rate-exchange-1.appspot.com',
        pathRewrite: {
            '^/api-currency': '/'
        }
    }},
]
```

**Error:**

```
FATAL  [HPM] Missing "target" option. Example: {target: "http://www.example.org"}
```

Comment: Can't you just use the object mode? (I can't even find the object mode documentation on nuxt website :( ), if you are using this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/proxy the array mode seems to have a slightly different form than the object mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In array mode config consists of arrays and strings.
If you use path with config its array:

```
[ path, { ...config } ]
```

not object

```
{ [path]: { ... config } }
```

example:

```
proxy: [
    ['/api', {
        target: 'https://nitro.noxgroup.co.za',
        pathRewrite: {
            '^/api': '/'
        }
    }],
    ['/api-currency', {
        target: 'https://rate-exchange-1.appspot.com',
        pathRewrite: {
            '^/api-currency': '/'
        }
    }],
]
```